# Defining node-sets with specific coordinates in Abaqus

Tags: set, coordinates, nodes, abaqus

I have a scripted simulation of a meshed soil area with varying locations of a wave barrier across 100 models. I have a certain number of nodes that I want to define as a set and read data such as velocity and displacement in those nodes, due to a dynamically applied load. My question is how to define sets of nodes with known coordinates?

Any suggestion would be really helpful.

```
    mdb.models['Model-%d' % (q)].rootAssembly.Set(name='Set-1', nodes=
        mdb.models['Model-%d' % (q)].rootAssembly.instances['Part-1-1'].nodes.sequenceFromLabels
        ((mdb.models['Model-%d' % (q)].rootAssembly.instances['Part-1-1'].nodes.getClosest((0,0.2,0 )).label,)))
```

I am getting the following error from the above lines:
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'label'